# Angular 10 error "Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations"

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a project with angular and angular material. Everything worked fine, but i decided to upgrade angular and angular material to v 10, because I needed a date range picker and this is only in the new version of these.
I made the update, but then when i start `ng serve -o` the console show me this error:

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/overlay-container.d.ts:8:53 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 import { InjectionToken, OnDestroy, Optional } from '@angular/core';
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/overlay-container.d.ts:10:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

10 import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
```

i tried cleaning the cache, then install @angular/material and @angular/cdk again. I tried rm -force node_modules... Anything works...So, i need help!

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "easytimer.js": "^4.3.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.23",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.6"
  }
}
```

And this is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "client:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "client:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}
```

Comment: Did you run this command - `npm install` ?

Comment: yes, i did and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
npm install --save @angular/core
```

keep using `npm install --save` to resolve subsequent errors

Answer (score 0):

Dont be frustrated i had the same error I solved by just re install npm or update the npm and after that again error not gone but output displays on browser so, i decided to reopen my Visual studio code and atlast it works fine.